# std::map check if a map has been assigned a non-default value?

Tags: c++, std, stdmap

Lets say I have a complex map defined as

```
std::map<int, std::pair< vector<int>, float> > complex_map;
```

Let us assume I initialized this map as

```
for (int k=0;k<5;k++)
{
    std::pair< vector<int>, float> complex_map_child;
    complex_map[k]=complex_map_child;
}
```

Next, I populate some entries of this map:

```
float test_1 = .7888;
vector<int> test_2;
test_2.push_back(1);
test_2.push_back(2);
complex_map[1].first = test_2;
complex_map[1].second = test_1;
```

So corresponding to key value 1 of complex_map, I have the pair of values corresponding to test_1 and test_2.

Now how do I check if I have explicitly added values to the map? i.e in this example how do I say that I havent explicitly filled up say complex_map[0]?

Comment: I do not understand what you are asking.

Comment: changed to better reflect the question!

Comment: `Now how do I check if I have explicitly added values to the map? or that they are in the original initialised state?`??? When you crate a map there are no values in it.  Are you trying to ask on how you can tell if a certain key exist in the map?

Comment: Maybe map::insert, which returns a pair<iterator, bool>, where the bool indicates an insertion (change)

Comment: You have to better define what you mean by "default". Why did you add 0-4 elements in the first place if you don't want them?

Comment: I dont understand your question, if you want to know if the map was having values when you initialized it in the for loop, then try to print them

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like you are using `std::map::operator[]` improperly and try to go over it - you are getting object like this:

```
auto &complex_value = complex_map[0];
```

and now you try to check if you inserted it before or it was implicitly created by `std::map::operator[]`.

Just do not use `std::map::operator[]` to access elements. Only use it when you need to set value in a map.

So proper solution would be to use different methods:

```
// I just want to check if key 0 is there
if( complex_map.count( 0 ) ) {
     ...
}

// I want to access element by key 0 if it is there
auto it = complex_map.find( 0 );
if( it != complex_map.end() ) {
    auto &complex_value = it->second;
    ...
}
```

and so on. I know that writing `complex_map[0]` is shorter but you are creating a problem that trying to solve convoluted way.

Answer (score 0):

> Now how do I check if I have explicitly added values to the map? i.e in this example how do I say that I havent explicitly filled up say complex_map[0]?

If by "explicitly" you mean you want to find elements that you wrote to after the initialisation loop that executed `complex_map[k]=complex_map_child;`, then:

- you can compare values in the map to `complex_map_child` to see if they're equal
- you can *not* detect if a map entry was written to with the same value, or changed then reverted (unless you change the data types to ones that track that themselves, or add some extra bookkeeping outside the `map` yourself)